# Jquery ajax request response 404 when make a post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am creating a basic friend request feature. This is one of the function I am working on, when Ajax send the post request it shows 404. It works if I put the code directly in the server.js file but I am trying to organize the code. Any solution? Thanks!

client.pug make a ajax request when user add friend by using email and hit submit

```
$('#addFriend').on('click', function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var searchByEmail = $('#searchByEmail').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/add',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    data: {
        email: searchByEmail
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
document.getElementById("searchByEmail").value = "";
$('#userModal').modal('hide'); });
```

controllers/friend.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const User = require('../models/user');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 var friendRequest = function() {
    app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
        var requestToEmail = req.body.email;
        console.log(requestToEmail);
        User.findOne({
            email: requestToEmail
        }, function(err, email) {
            if (!email) {
                console.log('cannot find the email', err);
                return res.send(err);
            }
            /*
            Add into database
            Display the friend list
            */
         })
     });
 } // End friend request

 module.exports = friendRequest;
```

server.js include and use the module

```
const friendInvite = require('./controllers/friend');
app.use('/friend', friendInvite);
```

file structure

```
- server.js
- controllers
  - friend.js
- views
  - client.pug
```

Comment: Is /add defined on .htaccess? You are requesting to your domain.com/add but I cannot see any related file or folder on your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your code on `controllers/friend.js` like below :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const User = require('../models/user');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var friendRequest = function() {
app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var requestToEmail = req.body.email;
    console.log(requestToEmail);
    User.findOne({
        email: requestToEmail
    }, function(err, email) {
        if (!email) {
            console.log('cannot find the email', err);
            return res.send(err);
        }
        /*
        Add into database
        Display the friend list
        */

        //add this response to client side
        res.json({ 'status': '200', 'desc': 'Success' });
     })
   });
 } // End friend request

module.exports = friendRequest;
```

you must send response to client side what is sign if the data has saved.
maybe you can try to check snippets code here :
https://github.com/egin10/node_mongoose/blob/master/routes/student.js

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see response in your app.post()
So it will be 404(Not found).

When you find a User, you can response something. 
For example, a 'success' message and friend list.

```
app.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    res.json(['success', friend list]);
});
```